# What type of motor is this, and how could the power be limited?

Tags: motor

I've got a aircondition unit (Wood's Cortina Silent 12K Wifi) that is way to powerful for the intended room. I'm hoping to limit the effect to 75-50% to reduce noise, but I have no idea how this should be done for this type of motor or AC unit.

Look at the picture attached for diagram coupling info. The details are as follows:

- 230 volt, 50Hz, 40W, 0.35A
- 4P, CL B, 3u F/450V
- Produced by Jiangsu Changjia Electric Co.
- Model: [YDK95-40-4E](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22YDK95-40-4%22) (NPB-12-206E)

I would love if it was as easy as adding a potensiometer or a light dimmer to one of the wires. I've seen suggestions of a frequency regulator as well. But I would not know if those things could heat or damage the motor or AC unit. Or even which of the wires to connect it.

[image: Motor and details]

Answer (score 5):

Your fan is multi speed, running it on a lower setting would help reduce the noise. Generally the fan is the most noisy part of an AC. The refrigeration side is engineered to operate in a given range, outside of that problems will occur. Changing the compressor speed would cause all types of problems that I do not believe you have the resources to properly accomplish your task. So my recommendation is to run it on the slowest speed and if too noisy get another AC unit.

Comment: Yes, the speed could be limited but the inbuilt speed does not go low enough. As the other person here pointed out, it's probably more a problem with the compressor and fan though. When that one kicks in, that's when the sound really get annoying.

Answer (score 5):

### Forget it, it not gonna happen.

What you have there is a "1-hose **portable** air conditioner".

The fan is not the part that is making the noise.  It's the A/C compressor mechanism.   And there's no way around it.  Here:

https://youtu.be/_-mBeYC2KGc?t=522

Nature of the beast.

And the loud thing - the compressor - *does not* lend itself to bolted-on speed control.  It only runs one speed, and can't be slowed.  The air movement fans could, which is what you're looking at there, but they're not the loud part.

Unfortunately, the idea of running the A/C for a good while to get the room nice-and-cold and then shutting it off for a long time, isn't really compatible with a 1-hose design because it's constantly sucking in hot wet air.

Even worse, the 1-hose unit is cooling your room, but is sucking outside air into the whole house.  That means the rest of the house is getting hotter, and if outside air is humid, it's also making the interior air wetter, including condensenation wich will add to mold and mildew.  The cure for *these* problems is a 2-hose unit, which also greatly improves efficiency, but that will do nothing for sound level or that jarring change.

Comment: yeah, get a 2-hose system or a portable split system.

Comment: You're right about the compressor/fan. I do have the unit in the room next to my bedroom, with ventilation to the room and outside venting. So, the setup is pretty ideal in this case. Just need to dampen the sound/vibration somewhat.

The compressor can probably never be limited, but perhaps it would help reducing the fan for the compressor somehow? Not sure if that's a good idea though. I'll try to dismantle the unit some more to see if I can pinpoint the loudest sound source.

I'm starting to believe that a solid sound proof box around the AC is the only real way of limiting this.

Comment: @Spud A solid soundproof box will hamper the air flow and probably alter the internal thermostat of the unit.

Comment: @Spud *Yeah, it's the compressor.*.  Since you're building enclosures, think about separating the airflows so you can convert it into a 2-hose system, to draw process air from outside. Lower electricity bills!